# Azure websites scaling issue

Tags: azure, scalability, azure-web-app-service

I am using a azure websites solution with 20 websites. Hosted on 4 cores, 8 GB RAM standard instance. I would like to know how I could do scaling in Azure websites and when to do it ?

Also I am reading some values from the new azure portal. 
Can someone guide me on the values that I see here ?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one who gets seemingly odd metrics from Azure.

Answer (score 1):

**Averages**

The Avg % is telling you, on average, how much of that resource is being used. So, if you have 8GB of ram, and you are typically using 66% of it, then you are averaging 5.28 Gb of ram used. Same goes for the CPU average listed below.

For the totals, I have no idea.

You're not using much of the CPU available to you here, but you are definitely taking advantage of the RAM. I'm not sure of what kind of web application you are running though, so it's dificult to determine what could be causing this.

**Scaling**

In terms of scaling, I always suggest starting with a small machine, then gradually scaling up.

Based on your usage, I'd drop to a machine that has fewer CPU cores, but more available RAM. From within your dashboard, you can see how to scale by clicking no your web app, then scrolling down. Click on the **scale** tab and it should appear as it does below:

[image]

You can now adjust what you want to scale by. The default setting is **CPU Percentage**, but that isn't particularly useful in this case. Instead, select **Schedule and performance rules** and a new panel wioll appear. On the right hand side, select **Metric name** and look for **Memory Percentage**.

In your particular case, this is helpful as we saw that your RAM is consistently being used.

[image]

Look at **Action** and you will want to **Increase count by** and change the number of VMs to 1. What this does is when your RAM reaches a certain usage %, Azure will auto-scale and generate a new VM for you. After a cool down period of 5 minutes (the default, listed at the bottom), your machine will revert to 1 machine.

**Conclusion**

With these settings, each time your website uses <= (Select your percentage) of RAM, Azure will increase the size of your machines.

In your case, I suggest using fewer cores, but more RAM.

Make sure you save your settings, with the **Save** button above.

Scott Hanselman as a [great blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudWhenDoAzureWebsitesMakeSense.aspx) on how to make sense of all of this.